# How to align div input tag and button on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am new in html and I have a [code](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17952/) where I would like to align the input tag and the button on the right sign on the same line. How can I do that?

```
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-btn input-group-addon">
        <button class="btn btn-del input-group-delete" data-tooltip="tooltip" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
```

My jsfiddle :      https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17952/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do it in this way...

```
<style>
.nopadding{
  padding:0;
}
</style>
<div class="timeline-panel">
  <div class="timeline-heading">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn input-group-addon nopadding">
                            <button class="btn btn-del input-group-delete" data-tooltip="tooltip" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Varun, it seems working but there are still a bit unequally on the bottom, here you can see it https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17962/

Comment: check it now 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17963/)
i added new class to button `btn_addon` and add css to it in which i decrease the 1px padding of button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap you can just add `pull-right` in the input field and button both.
For example:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" />
```

In button as well:

```
 <button class="btn btn-del input-group-delete pull-right" data-tooltip="tooltip" >
```

Comment: You can also add pull-right on div. i am not sure about this one. Just try once

Comment: Hi Srijan, unfortunately it took no influences, https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17955/

Comment: ohh then did u call the bootstrap class on top? Add this on head section:  
`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: If that too does not work then u probably should add jquery at the top:  
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this

```
<div class="timeline-panel">
  <div class="timeline-heading">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-del input-group-delete col-xs-3" data-tooltip="tooltip" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17959/) Update this according your need

Comment: Hi Jayant, the problem is that inside the <span> tag I have not only the <i> tag, but also including one <button> and that why this button can not be align on the same line with the <input> tag

Comment: I already tried if I removed the button then I works fine, they are on the same line, but if I add the button then they are not on the same line

Comment: you have to put input tag inside div

Comment: could you please send me again the answer

Answer (score 0):

While using addon in bootstrap if you define any element inside the addon span it will cluttered because in bootstrap the addon class have padding in css and that is way you button will not aligned  in this case you can do it like this :

```
<div class="timeline-panel">
  <div class="timeline-heading">
    <div class="form-horizontal col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn input-group-addon btn btn-del input-group-delete"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```